# Stripe how to retrieve a Checkout Session's line items quantity?

Tags: stripe-payments

Create payment Sessions :

```
$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'], //, 'fpx','alipay'
    'line_items' => [[
        'price_data' => [
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => "Topup USDT Wallet",
                'images' => ["https://abc-uaha.co/uploads/site_logo/site_logo_20210321130054.png"],
                'metadata' => [
                    'pro_id' => "USD".$_GET['price']/100
                ]
            ],
            'unit_amount' => $_GET['price'],
            'currency' => 'usd',
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
        'description' => "Spartan Capital",
    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => STRIPE_SUCCESS_URL.'?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    'cancel_url' => STRIPE_CANCEL_URL,
]);
```

Refer to this docs : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items

I tried retrieve quantity from session:

```
try {
    $checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::retrieve([
      'id' =>$session_id,
      'expand' => ['line_items'],
     ]);
}catch(Exception $e) { 
    $api_error = $e->getMessage(); 
}

$line_items = $session->line_items[0].quantity;

echo $line_items; //it shows nothing, how to make it output "1"?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line_items` are no longer included by default when retrieving Checkout Sessions. To get them in your retrieve call, you need to [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the `line_item` property.

You have two syntax errors :
You're missing a layer and using dot notation instead of PHP arrow syntax. The 2nd error is using `$session` instead of `$checkout_session`. So it should be :

`$quantity = $checkout_session->line_items->data[0]->quantity`;

Comment: did u see the code on my question `expand' => ['line_items']` ?

Comment: You're missing a layer and using dot notation instead of PHP arrow syntax. It should be `$quantity = $session->line_items->data[0]->quantity;`

Comment: tried your syntax correction, it still output empty

Comment: tried `$quantity = $session->line_items[0][quantity];` also show empty.. Can't find docs show correct syntax

Comment: ok i found the syntax error already. Use `$checkout_session` instead of `$session`. Thank you very much for your guide . `$quantity = $checkout_session->line_items->data[0]->quantity`;